# Send stream of data from .exe to image viewer

Tags: c#, process

I want to do something like the following. If I have, say, an image file incoroporated into my program data as a string, can I somehow send that image as data to an image viewer and view it normally, without creating a permanent file in order to do so? The language to be used is C#.

Comment: Why would an image be in a string? in what format? - If a 3rd party external viewer only loads images from disk (as most do) then you will need to create a temporary file for it to open.

Comment: What I want is for the final data to be sent from the exe to the viewer, without the possibility for the said data to be "intercepted" or leave a trace notable for a normal user at any point of the process. No matter whether it's in string format or not, it will be somehow held only by the program, before it is sent to the viewer.

Comment: What is *viewer*? Another your software? Then sure, design/use secure [IPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574.aspx) protocol, so nothing can *intercept* your data.

Comment: I was looking whether there would be a way to do this with the tools already provided by .NET. Of course, that being impossible is also an answer. And, I have not created my own viewer for the job,yet.

Comment: If you dont like permanent files, use a in-memory database instead. Try sqlite.